# Postgresql SUM valus for large table very slow

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum

I have a table which includes the movements of articles of a warehouse.
Now I have to calculate the current stock after the movement, in retrospect.

In my table I have a field "quantity" which hold the amount of the movement, negative number for outgoing, positive numer for incoming movements.

Right now the table has around 2'000'000 records.

To SUM I use following SQL and pass a date.
But it's very slow it has runner over 10h and it's still not done.
I also tried to use a MATERIALIZED VIEW but didn't helped to get a better performance

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    vSum INTEGER;
    tables CURSOR FOR
        SELECT a.mov_id, a.timestamp FROM movements a 
BEGIN
   FOR lo1 IN tables LOOP
      SELECT SUM(b.quantity)
      INTO vSum
      FROM movements b
      WHERE b.timestamp <= lo1.timestamp;
    
      UPDATE movements
      SET current_stock = vSum
      WHERE mov_id = lo1.mov_id;
           
   END LOOP;
END; $$
```

EDIT:

Trying to explain want I want to reach with an image.
I added a new field inside my table "current_stock".
Now I need to update this field with the correct values. That what my SQL is for.

For Example
If I pass the date "03.10.2020 15:24:13", I want my SQL to sum the quantity of every record which is before this date to get the current stock.
In my exampe it should SUM the VALUES "15, -3, -3"a dn then update current_stock

[image]

Comment: An aggregation query over 2 million records should not be taking 10 hours.  Perhaps the table is locked or the "table" is really a complex view.

Comment: also you can create an index on `b.timestamp` column. if `select` has issue, it will impact both table and view in similar way.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Maybe I explained wrong. I'm not Summing twi million rows at once. I loop through every movement (2 million) and pass the date to my SQL. This sum the all records to a given date. Can it be a probem if I use the sae table for loop and sum?

Comment: If I understand that code correctly you are trying to update each row wit the sum of the quantity until that row. As far as I can tell this can be done with a single update statement: https://pastebin.com/jMA0WySt

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5a9ac5962f6b743dd5d2a2ceacb26127